# vi background color wrong on Windows 10 1903 WSL Terminal

Tags: terminal, microsoft-windows

After upgrading to Windows 10 1903 (18362.175), in Window Subsystem for Linux (WSL) Ubuntu 18.04, the background color is always set to black when scrolling backward in `vi`, `vim`, `man` and maybe some other tools. 
[image: man ls background color wrong]
Is there a workaround involving vi configuration or shell commands? (I would rather not install a different terminal emulator.)

Answer (score 1):

This Windows 10 terminal issue is documented in [Vim background color renders incorrectly](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/832).  A workaround is to set the vi background color to one of 16 working colors.
In ~/.vimrc put:

```
highlight Normal ctermfg=black ctermbg=lightgrey
```

When in vim, this sets the text color to black and the background color to lightgrey.
Use `:help cterm-colors` in vim to see other working color names.

Also, in Windows 10 1903, Linux files can now be accessed from Windows.  See [link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/whats-new-for-wsl-in-windows-10-version-1903/)
So a graphical editor like gvim (https://www.vim.org/download.php) can be used.

Comment: This appears to be a different issue.